# Rendering issue using Ng-repeat, track by and limitto together

Tags: angularjs

In my project, i am using ng-repeat with limitto filter and track by $index

```
<button ng-disabled="currentPage == 0" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage-1">Previous</button>
<button ng-disabled="currentPage >= cil.cilChemicals.length/pageSize - 1" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage+1">Next</button>

<div ng-repeat="chemical in Chemicals | startFrom: currentPage * pageSize  | limitTo:pageSize track by $index">
    <span ng-init="initDetails(chemical)"> {{chemical.details}} </span>
</div>
```

Controller code :

```
$scope.currentPage = 0; 
$scope.pageSize = 50;

Module.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) { 
        start = +start;
        return input.slice(start);
    }
});
```

With this setup, `initDetails(chemical)` is called for all chemicals during first time ng-repeat rendering thus not called for each page which is rendered perfectly for the first time but when we repeat the page then ng-repeat starts re rendering from in between the array.

Please suggest why it starts from in between and when we use `trackby chemical.chemicalId`then angular js calls `initDetails(chemical)`for each page.

Comment: the track by should be just after the repeat iteration no ? `"chemical in Chemicals  track by $index | startFrom: currentPage * pageSize  | limitTo:pageSize"`

Comment: can you create plunker?

Comment: I think your using `ngInit` wrong, the red box on the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) Also your syntax of the expression is fine, `track by` needs to be the very last expression. [under arguments table at bottom](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Comment: Basically when we repeat the page ie click on 1 again then ng-repeat starts re rendering from in between the array and calls the initDetails(chemical) from that index instead of starting from 0.

Comment: what is the use of this `initDetails(chemical)` can you provide the code?

Answer (score 1):

The way you have `ng-init`, runs in each iteration.

Except (enters track by):
when you use `trackby $index` the first element has always the `$index` 0 regardless of page number,
so angular **doesn't** re-render the html

but when you change the `trackby` to `chemical.chemicalIdthen` angular re-renders the html in evey iteration.

Actually angular will re-render **only** the items that have diff in the track by expression, either it is an index or id, than the previous items.

Also I agree with @ste2425's comment. that is not the intended use of `ng-init`

*just a note:*

LimitTo filter accepts 2 parameters, `limit` and `begin`,
`limit` is the page size, and `begin` is the index to start counting, so there is no need to create a custom filter for that.

You can essentially do this:

```
<button ng-disabled="currentPage == 0" ng-click="previousPage()">Previous</button>
<button ng-disabled="currentPage >= cil.cilChemicals.length/pageSize - 1" ng-click="nextPage()">Next</button>

<div ng-repeat="chemical in Chemicals | limitTo:pageSize:startFrom track by $index">
    <span ng-init="initDetails(chemical)"> {{chemical.details}} </span>
</div>
```

And your controller

```
$scope.currentPage = 0; 
$scope.pageSize = 50;
scope.startFrom = 0

$scope.nextPage = function() {
    $scope.currentPage++;
    $scope.startFrom = $scope.currentPage * $scope.pageSize;
};

$scope.previousPage = function() {
    $scope.currentPage--;
    $scope.startFrom = $scope.currentPage * $scope.pageSize;
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this but still ng-repeat is rendering again from in between (i.e. init function is called from in between not from 0) when we come again on same page moreover we have not changed the list so why its re rendering.

Comment: see this example [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3FGerIK8gW7pVHdVbOhS?p=preview) can you reproduce your bug here?

Comment: see this updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rJlt7b4ZkfHTuHD21JGy?p=preview) in which initDetails() is called while filtering as well even when we have not changed the data.

Comment: What I see is that ngInit is called 2 times on first iteration and not on page change, and if you remove the trackby $index it gets called in each page 2 times all with index 0,1 which is normal.

Comment: see this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QaWZZJRQfsiMDfPq65lb?p=preview). how can continue the convrsation in chat?

Comment: [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112135/rendering-issue-using-ng-repeat-track-by-and-limitto-together)

Comment: Refer this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZzZB/2714/) in which when i use 'trackby $index', angular calls initDetails() 9 times on page load and then after traversing till 5th page there is no rendering but when i press previous button, angular re renders and its not from 0 its from 5(refer console). Please suggest about this behaviour of angular.